# Programmatically adding Outlook Addin+Access Denied

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2013

I have Outlook 2013 Addin Project to add a custom AddIn. When I run the project,
the outlook opens up . Then when we proceed to add the specific Addin, it says access denied issue to the specific custom addin project dll. All the permissions have been given.  I rebuild and run the project everytime , hence the dll will anyways be created always so do not understand what extra permission needs to be given or is it some other issue

Regards
Raghav

Comment: > Then when we proceed to add the specific Addin - What code do you use? Could you please be more specific?

Comment: There  is a default project option in Visual Studio to create Outlook2013 addins. I just create the same and  ran that  without any change in the code .So basically it is addin with no functionality inside.On running the project, the outlook application opens but as I said , when we try to map the specific addin from the "addin manager" it says  "Access denied to the XXX.dll. The dll basically is the one mapping to  the outlook project I created

Comment: Why do you need to "map" the add-in? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Basically  the requirement is to create a custom addin and add to outlook. Ideally when the outlook is launched by running this Outlook2013 project, the addin should be added but it fails with the access denied issue as said before. So I tried to remap again from the outllook addin manager but the same issue.

Comment: There is no need to add the add-in manually. You need to find why the dll is blocked in VS.